# SQL getting a minimum value from an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a minimum value to return from an agregate function. I have created a query that executes, but fails to return only the one minimum row for each group. In this example, there are multiple rows for each prod_num, each with a unique serial number. This is for SQL Server.

My code:

```
SELECT 
    x.prod_num, Min(x.sn) sn, y.qty, x.date_tested,x.scrap
FROM 
    serial_numbers x
JOIN 
    prod_ord y on y.prod_num = x.prod_num
WHERE
    x.date_tested IS NOT NULL 
    AND x.scrap = 1
GROUP BY 
    x.prod_num, x.sn, y.qty, x.date_tested, x.scrap
ORDER BY 
    x.date_tested desc, x.prod_num
```

My results:

```
prod_num    sn            qty   date_tested           scrap
------------------------------------------------------------
301336662   120214A10338    7   2014-12-09 19:26:41.650 1
301336662   120214A10339    7   2014-12-09 19:26:41.650 1
301336662   120214A10340    7   2014-12-09 19:26:41.650 1
301336662   120214A10341    7   2014-12-09 19:26:41.650 1
301336662   120214A10342    7   2014-12-09 19:26:41.650 1
301336662   120214A10343    7   2014-12-09 19:26:41.650 1
301336662   120214A10344    7   2014-12-09 19:26:41.650 1
301303464   101014A11003    4   2014-10-16 15:18:06.817 1
301303464   101014A11004    4   2014-10-16 15:18:06.817 1
301303464   101014A11005    4   2014-10-16 15:18:06.817 1
301303464   101014A11006    4   2014-10-16 15:18:06.817 1
301293879   100714A10258    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
301293879   100714A10259    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
301293879   100714A10260    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
301293879   100714A10261    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
301293879   100714A10262    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
301293879   100714A10263    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
301293879   100714A10264    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
301293879   100714A10265    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
301293879   100714A10266    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
```

What I am really trying to get is only one row for each `prod_num`, the row with the smallest `sn`.

Like this.

```
prod_num    sn            qty   date_tested           scrap
------------------------------------------------------------
301336662   120214A10338    7   2014-12-09 19:26:41.650 1
301303464   101014A11003    4   2014-10-16 15:18:06.817 1
301293879   100714A10258    15  2014-10-13 13:23:58.923 1
```

Can someone please point me to where I am going wrong?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove x.sn from the group by...

Your statement of:

```
SELECT x.prod_num, Min(x.sn) sn, y.qty, x.date_tested,x.scrap
FROM serial_numbers x
JOIN prod_ord y on y.prod_num = x.prod_num
where x.date_tested is not NULL and x.scrap = 1
group by x.prod_num, x.sn, y.qty, x.date_tested,x.scrap
order by x.date_tested desc, x.prod_num
```

Should be:

```
SELECT x.prod_num, Min(x.sn) sn, y.qty, x.date_tested,x.scrap
FROM serial_numbers x
JOIN prod_ord y on y.prod_num = x.prod_num
where x.date_tested is not NULL and x.scrap = 1
group by x.prod_num, y.qty, x.date_tested,x.scrap
order by x.date_tested desc, x.prod_num
```

You're telling the engine to group by x.sn which it's doing, but you only want the minimum one.  By removing the x.sn from the group by, you should get your desired result.

Comment: @wallenpb Yes, **VERY** close.  Generally speaking, you don't want to group by the values being aggregated; `min(x.sn)` in this case.

Comment: How is it that a query such as the following does not produce the same number of rows as what I would think would be equivalent using group by?                                                                     SELECT prod_num, sn,date_tested,scrap
FROM serial_numbers 
where date_tested is not NULL and scrap = 1 
and sn = (select MIN(sn) from serial_numbers a where a.prod_num = serial_numbers.prod_num)
order by date_tested desc,prod_num

Comment: I don't think the the coorlated subquery is doing what you think it is. Wouldn't MIN always return the lowest serial number?  Put another way if you do `(select MIN(sn) 
              from serial_numbers)` as the sub query in the where clause, don't you get the same results? a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would help.  I applaud you for taking the time to think about the answer provided, and not just applying it.  I guess I need to see the two different queries next to each other and some sample data to fully get this...  You've also eliminated an INNER Join which could change the results

Comment: Yes, you are right.  What is interesting is that when doing it with the group by on my data, I get 6 rows.  When using the correlated subquery, I only get 4 - two results are missed.  My reasoning on the correlated subsquery is that the self join on serial_numbers with the two copies of the prod_num column being equal would group the data by prod_num, then would return the Min sn from any prod_num that are equal.  You are right that this is not doing what I thought.  The group by method clearly gives me correct and complete results.  Just a little perplexed why the other does not.

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble visualizing the data or I'm sure I could figure out the 6 vs 4 and explain what's happening.  Hopefully we've put you on the right path and helped you learn along the way.

Comment: Yes, very helpful.  Thank you.   I may start a new inquiry along similar lines that is more clear as to what I am doing.